# UIButton Background image Change on Click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a tableView showing some controls.Like options for the correct ans in UIButton.I want to change the buttons background image in the correct ans and the wrong ans in the click event.how can i do this?Can any one give me a idea? 
i am trying to change the background image as :

```
 [cell.ansBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

and i have set the backgound as :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeginingCell";

     cell=(BeginingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

               NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeginingCell" owner:self options:nil ];

        for(id CurrentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([CurrentObject isKindOfClass:[BeginingCell class]]) {

                cell=(BeginingCell *) CurrentObject;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


                break;
            }
        }

    }


    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {


                imageURL=[dictionary objectForKey:@"questionImage"];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURL];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]  initWithData:data];



        cell.lblScoreCurrent.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", reloader];

        cell.lblScore.text=@"/30";
        cell.myImageView.image = img;
        cell.SectionTitle.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"];




        cell.ansBtn1.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.ansBtn2.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.ansBtn3.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.ansBtn4.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;



        cell.ansBtn1.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.ansBtn2.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.ansBtn3.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.ansBtn4.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;


        [cell.ansBtn1 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn2 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn3 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn4 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [cell.ansBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.ansBtn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.ansBtn3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.ansBtn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    }


    return cell;

}
```

And here is the click Event :

```
      -(void) btnAction:(id) sender {

NSString *str =((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;

NSLog(@"%@",str);
NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);

correctAns=[dictionary objectForKey:@"answer"];

if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"])
{
    selectedAns=@"1";

    if ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) 
    {

    [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
     NSLog(@"this is correct");

     countCorrect++;
     cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];


    }

    else 
    {

        [cell.ansBtn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

}

else if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"])
{
    selectedAns=@"2";
    if ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        [cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        NSLog(@"this is correct");
        countCorrect++;
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {
        [cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }
}


else if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"])
{

    selectedAns=@"3";
    NSLog(@"selected ans is %@",selectedAns);
    NSLog(@"correct ans is %@",correctAns);

    if ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) 
    {
        [cell.ansBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        NSLog(@"this is correct");

        countCorrect++;
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {
        [cell.ansBtn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

}

else if(str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"])
{

    selectedAns=@"4";
    NSLog(@"selected ans is %@",selectedAns);
    NSLog(@"correct ans is %@",correctAns);

    if ([selectedAns compare:correctAns]==NSOrderedSame) 
    {

        [cell.ansBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

        countCorrect++;
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];

    }

    else 
    {
        [cell.ansBtn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        cell.lblRating.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countCorrect];            

    }

}


else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR");
}


reloader++;

if (reloader>=[QuestionMutableArray count]) {



    NSString *str=[self GetSkill];
    NSString *totalTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i . %i minutes",7-timeMin,60-timeSecond];
    NSString *str2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Game Over :\n Knowlwdge Level : %@  \n Total Correct Answer :%i \n Total Time : %@ \n Total Question Answered : %i \n",str,countCorrect,totalTime,reloader];

    appAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Game Over :\n" message:str2 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [appAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"PlayAgain"];



    UIImage *alertBoxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_look.jpg"];

    UIImageView *_backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertBoxImage];

    _backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 220);

    _backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    [appAlert addSubview:_backgroundImageView];

    [appAlert sendSubviewToBack:_backgroundImageView]; 


    [appAlert show];        
    [dictionary release];
    [QuestionMutableArray release];
    countCorrect=0;


}
else {

    dictionary=[QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:reloader];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

}
```

problem is when i am clicking a button for the first time the background is not changing.but in the next click i am getting the change according to the change logic set(i mean green/red change)...what should i do in this case.What is the solution?

Comment: and also use compare: to compare the strings

Comment: what's wrong with comparing two string with == operator?

Comment: and please tell me how can i use isEqualToOperator here str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"]

Comment: please tell me how can i compare like you told from a dictionary string here :str==[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**More Edit:**
Don't use `==` to check if the strings are equal or not, instead use isEqualToString: or compare: function

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

you can do

```
if([string1 compare:string2] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    //Do something...
}
```

because `==` will check 2 pointers address in memory location and not the contents of those pointers.

**OLD**

You can use

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setBackgroundImage:forState:

or

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:

If you are showing ans as title label of button, then you have to use `setBackgroundImage:forState:`

**Edit**
instead of

```
 [cell.ansBtn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

you should use

```
 [cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_red.png"]  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

cause you also have to show your ans as title label of that button.

Comment: i am using [cell.ansBtn1 setTitle:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; for sgowing the ans...ok i am taking a look at your ans

Comment: you need to set the background image of the button when the user presses a button thats it.

Comment: i did it..it's changing..but i want to reset it with normal background imega after the clickeven.How can i do this.And another issue...when i am setting the background image my labeltext is hiding.i dont't want this..please see my code :

Comment: [cell.ansBtn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"option_green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; no backgound is showing using this code..

Comment: i tried with your code..but image change effect is now working..no image is showing...i tried changing all the states..

Comment: ok...i am getting the change..but after the click i want to reload it as it was when it's loaded with new data....the change is not cleaned when i am getting the new data..how can i do this?

Comment: it's working now.. with the background highlighted.Now tell me how can i make this effect on two button in the same click...and why it's working with highlighted?Any idea?

Comment: may be you have set the highlighted property of button

Comment: how can i make this change to two button clicking in one?

Comment: have a same selector method for both the buttons and in that method just change the background image of both buttons

Comment: also remove the unnecessary comments from this answer. other wise people might mark it as spam.

Comment: I have updated the working code..now please help with making changes in two button....if i click a wrong ans...it's background will be red and it'll show the correct ans by changing the background with green image...

Comment: ok...i am having big problem..when for this first time i am clicking the image is not changing in the button..but in second click it's changing...as a result...i am getting miss mass with the correct ans and wrong ans indication..what can i do now?

Comment: you can mail me the code but i will take a look at it on sat.  if you want i can give u my email id

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju @robin - It is better if code is posted here, for the benefit of everyone viewing this question in the future.

Comment: @All : here i have updated the code...please take a look..tell me how can i resolve this issue.....

Answer (score 0):

Add target methods in your UIbutton. Define it -(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender. Then create button from sender object in the this method so whenever we click on button, we will get the sender object and change it background image using setBackgroundImage method of button. This may help you.